# EditText and keyboard in android app

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have problem with delete key.

When I add `EditText` to my app I can write, but I can't delete chars.

What is wrong?

```
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/typeCode"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="@string/type_code"
                android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:lines="1"
                android:maxLength="6"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
```

It was my problem:

```
@Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event){
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){

            alertDialog.show();
        }    
        return false;
    }
```

Change to:

```
@Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event){
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){

            alertDialog.show();
              return false;
        }else{
              return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
        }
    }
```

Tnx, for help.

Comment: Could you please explain the problem a little bit?

Comment: I can't find any idea to explain it.
I have edittext in xml and it is all.
When I write in, I can't delete it.

Comment: Can you post the code for it, can you show us a screenshot of what is happening? Have you tried a different keyboard? What version are you running? Is it on the emulator or a real device? We need detail...

Comment: It is on device.
I added my code.

Comment: Are you sure you are pressing the `backspace` and not the `enter`? They look quite similar

Comment: Pop your answer in and close it off, fair play in resolving it!